# Circle DIV elements next to each other

Tags: html, css, css-float, geometry

I'm making a data visualization for a school assignment. I have a lot of circle div elements with different sizes. Is it possible to get them next to each other? Now I used float: left; but then the div elements are on 1 row, and if one is bigger there is a white space.

Webpage: http://i290808.iris.fhict.nl/dv3/

Example of 1 circle HTML:

```
<div class="circle" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; border: 15px solid rgb(255, 141, 0); background-image: url('http://zapp.trakt.us/images/episodes/9635-4-11.jpg?17'); background-size: cover;">
    <div class="circle" style="height: 100%; background-color:rgba(255, 146, 0, 0.4)">
        <h2 style="font-size: 25px">New Girl</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

(There are style elements in this HTML element, because I need to change this information in my PHP file)

CSS file:

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: table;
    float: left;
}

h2 {
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Please dont link to your webpage as it may be removed in the future, rendereing the link a dead one :)

Comment: Also, why is your header `display:table-cell`? Anything other than block, inline and inline-block should only be used when really needed, not as a quick fix :)

Comment: @Ruben Please find the answers below and mark one as accepted that solves your problem.

Comment: @Martijn Sorry for the link, I wanted to replace it with a picture, but I need first a reputation of 10. I will replace it when I have these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following rules.

```
h2 {
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-top: 50%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.circle {
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Additionally, to center your `.circles` horiontally wrap all `.circles` in a `#container` div and give it the following rule.

```
#container {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the result.

[image]

Comment: Great solution but the titles are not in the middle in Safari on the Mac, Chrome works great. I hope there is a simple solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Bubble Chart using d3.js will best suit your needs.

Here's a working code snippet:

```js
var data = {
  "name": "animate",
  "children": [
    {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
    {
      "name": "interpolate",
      "children": [
        {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
        {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
        {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
        {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
        {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
        {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
        {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
        {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
        {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
      ]
    },
    {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
    {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
    {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
    {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
    {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
    {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
    {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
    {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
  ]
};


var diameter = 960,
    format = d3.format(",d"),
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
.sort(null)
.size([diameter, diameter])
.padding(1.5);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", diameter)
.attr("height", diameter)
.attr("class", "bubble");

//d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(bubble.nodes(classes(data))
      .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

node.append("title")
.text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

node.append("circle")
.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

node.append("text")
.attr("dy", ".3em")
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
//});

// Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
function classes(data) {
  var classes = [];

  function recurse(name, node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
    else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
  }

  recurse(null, data);
  return {children: classes};
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");
```

```css
text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Regarding adding the background image to each bubble, you may add the respective paths to every *children* in the input data and then apply it using d3.js.

[Various D3.js Bubble Chart tutorials | Google](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=d3+bubble+chart+tutorial)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Thanks for pointing out. Updated my answer with an example in the snippet and relevant content.

Comment: @jproffitt Thanks for pointing out. Updated my answer with an example in the snippet and relevant content.

Comment: This is a nice solution for the future, but now I don't use a json file to load the information.